# Scala Swing scrollbar for TextArea

Tags: scala, scroll, gridbaglayout, scala-swing

I'm trying to add a scrollbar to a text area component. I could use FlowPanel, but I need to use GridBagPanel for my other components and when I tried to add a flowpanel inside the gridbagpanel it was empty and like 2x2 pixels.

Is there a way to add two panels to a MainFrame or add the scrollbar some other way?